# Android Feeding images from a Json Feed into a list

Tags: android, json, image

Hi i have a list i have it filling in a title from a Json Feed and now i want to add an image to it heres my single_list layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_gr_arrow"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
   android:textColor="@color/blue"
   android:padding="20dp"
   android:textSize="10dp" 

     />


</RelativeLayout>
```

heres the an example of one news story from the JSON Feed i think it image_small i need

```
{"code":200,"error":null,"data":{"news":[{"news_id":"8086","title":"Tickets for Player of the Year award on general sale","tagline":"Event to be held Sunday 25th March at Holiday Inn, Barnsley","content":"Tickets for the inaugural Evo-Stik NPL Player of the Year event are now on sale to the general public.\r\n\r\nPriced at \u00a335, tickets include a three course meal, plus entertainment from renowned tenor Martin Toal and guest speaker Fred Eyre.\r\n\r\nAwards at the event include the Player and Young Player of the Year for each division, as well as divisional teams of the year, the Fans\u2019 Player of the Year and a League Merit award.\r\n\r\nTo purchase your ticket, send a cheque for \u00a335 payable to \u201cNorthern Premier League\u201d to Alan Ogley, 21 Ibberson Avenue, Mapplewell, Barnsley, S75 6BJ. Please include a return address for the tickets to be sent to, and the names of those attending. \r\n\r\nFor more information, e-mail Tom Snee or contact Event organiser Alan Ogley on 07747 576 415\r\n\r\nNote: Clubs can still order tickets by e-mailing Angie Firth - simply state how many tickets you require and you will be invoiced accordingly.\r\n\r\nAddress of venue: Barnsley Road, Dodworth, Barnsley S75 3JT (just off Junction 37 of M1)","created":"2012-02-29 12:00:00","category_id":"1","img":"4539337","category":"General","fullname":"Tom Snee","user_id":"170458","image_user_id":"170458","image_file":"1330519210_0.jpg","image_width":"600","image_height":"848","sticky":"1","tagged_division_id":null,"tagged_team_id":null,"tagged_division":null,"tagged_team":null,"full_image":"http:\/\/images.pitchero.com\/up\/league-news-default-full.png","image_primary":"http:\/\/images.pitchero.com\/ui\/170458\/lnl_1330519210_0.jpg","image_secondary":"http:\/\/images.pitchero.com\/ui\/170458\/lns_1330519210_0.jpg","image_original":"http:\/\/images.pitchero.com\/ui\/170458\/1330519210_0.jpg","image_small":"http:\/\/images.pitchero.com\/ui\/170458\/sm_1330519210_0.jpg"}
```

and heres my code so far

```
String json = reader.readLine();





            // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();


            JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("news");


            for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {    JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                items.add(oneObject.getString("title"));
                 Log.i("items", "items");
            }

            setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, items));
            ListView list = getListView();
            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),1000).show();
                }



            });


        } catch(Exception e){
            // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to load Image for every items in your listview, if this is the case then you can implement any solution from below:

1. [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)
2. [Android Universal Image Loader by Nostra](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).